# Core Data - iCloud behavior

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I am implementing iCloud support in my core data app using an NSManagedDocument as the core data stack.

Everything seems to be working fine but with some unexpected behavior:

With the universal app installed on my iPhone and iPad:

an entity added from the iPhone gets iClouded to the iPad; 
an entity added from the iPad gets iClouded to the iPhone;
the entity added from the iPhone, deleted on the iPhone is automatically deleted on the iPad
the entity added from the iPad, deleted on the iPad is automatically deleted on the iPhone

However ...

the entity added from the iPhone, deleted on the iPad is not deleted on the iPhone
the entity added from the iPad, deleted on the iPhone is not deleted on the iPad

Is this the expected behavior?  This is not how the Apple 'notes' app behaves on my iPhone and iPad.  Any changes to any notes are reflected across all devices.

If this is not the correct iCloud behavior, any ideas where I might have gone astray?

Thanks so much.

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> *Is this the expected behavior?*

That depends on how you define "expected". It's not how Apple intends it to work, but you're not the first person to run into this problem. In practice, yeah, it's expected at least some of the time.

A couple of things you should check:

- Does this condition persist even if you quit and re-launch the app? It could be that the instance is getting deleted but that your app isn't updating its UI properly. That would make it appear that the object was still there, until you relaunched the app.
- Take a look at the "did import" notification you receive from iCloud. It should contain object IDs for inserted, updated, and deleted instances. Make sure it correctly indicates which object(s) have been deleted on the receiving end.
- Check out your object handling to make sure you're not somehow holding on to the object that should have been deleted, or re-creating it.

But keep in mind, if you're using Core Data with iCloud, **you are asking for trouble** and you may not be able to fix this. Core Data's iCloud integration is still not all that reliable. Expect problems, potentially too severe to fix.